# Finite Permutation Composition

Tags: permutations, function-and-relation-composition

This is a problem I'm trying to solve. Given a permutation $ \sigma $ on a finite set $ \mathcal{A} $ of order $ n $, show that there exists a positive integer $ 0< k \leq n $ such that

$$\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix}
a_1&a_2&...&a_n \\ b_1&b_2&...&b_n
\end{smallmatrix}
\bigr)^k = \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix}
a_1&a_2&...&a_n \\ a_1&a_2&...&a_n
\end{smallmatrix}
\bigr)
$$

Comment: Have you thought about the problem? Tested it, to make sure it's true, and gotten a feel for *why* it's true? Or are you not understanding the question statement? Because without any of your own input, the question's kind of begging to be closed.

Comment: It must be true. Why? Thinking of a group of permutation $ S_n $ on a finite set, and the fact that every element in $ S_n $ has a finite order. However I want to show it's true using a pure permutation approach.

Comment: If $\pi=(12)(345)$, then $\pi^2=(354)$, $\pi^3=(12)$, $\pi^4=(345)$, $\pi^5=(12)(354)$, $\pi^6=identity$.

Comment: Hints: Write the permutation as a product of disjoint cycles. Play around with powers of cycles, and with powers of products of disjoint cycles, to figure out what the value of $k$ is in terns of the original cycle decomposition.